# WebSocket between ESP32 and Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket, esp32

I would like to use websocket on ESP32 for communication with java websocket server. I'm using code example from ESP32 documentation:
https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/a45e99853/examples/protocols/websocket

Things which I adjusted are ssid name and password and websocket endpoint address. My java code looks following:

```
package com.webapp.ws;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/hello")
public class HelloEndpoint {
    private Session session;

    @OnOpen
    public void onCreateSession(Session session){
        System.out.println("Connected " + session.toString());
        this.session = session;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void OnTextMessage(String message){
        System.out.println("message=" + message);
        if(this.session != null && this.session.isOpen()){
            try {
                System.out.println("received: " + message);
                this.session.getBasicRemote().sendText("From server: " + message);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HelloEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable thr) {
        Logger.getLogger(HelloEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, thr.toString());

    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't get communication between esp and java (hosted on tomee). Logs from ESP are following:

```
I (8088) tcpip_adapter: sta ip: 192.168.1.100, mask: 255.255.255.0, gw: 192.168.1.1
I (8588) example_connect: Connected to Lubinska123
I (8588) example_connect: IPv4 address: 192.168.1.100
I (8588) example_connect: IPv6 address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:3e71:bfff:fef9:6db0
I (8598) WEBSOCKET: Connectiong to ws://192.168.1.104:8080/MvnWebAppSock/hello...
I (8678) WEBSOCKET: WEBSOCKET_EVENT_CONNECTED
I (9608) WEBSOCKET: Sending hello 0000
I (10608) WEBSOCKET: Sending hello 0001
I (11608) WEBSOCKET: Sending hello 0002
I (12608) WEBSOCKET: Sending hello 0003
I (13608) WEBSOCKET: Sending hello 0004
I (14608) WEBSOCKET: Sending hello 0005
I (15608) WEBSOCKET: Sending hello 0006
I (16618) WEBSOCKET: Sending hello 0007
I (17618) WEBSOCKET: Sending hello 0008
I (18618) WEBSOCKET: Sending hello 0009
I (18898) WEBSOCKET: WEBSOCKET_EVENT_DATA
I (18898) WEBSOCKET: Received opcode=10
W (18898) WEBSOCKET: Received=

I (19908) WEBSOCKET: Websocket Stopped
```

On tomcat logs I can only see that new connection was created and that's all. That means OnMessage annotation isn't called anytime.

Does anyone can help me with this issue?

Comment: why websocket? is the server a web server or a client a web page? Plain TCP socket isn't good enough?

Comment: @Juraj I need to control ESP from WebApp and send notifications from ESP to WebApp (e.g. update view by ajax). As I know it's not possible to run plain TCP/UDP thread on web server (tomEE). So that's reason why I would like to use WebSockets or REST for data exchange.

Comment: it is not Ajax if ESP32 C++ is the client